# JavaScript library for formatting AND parsing Date and Numbers

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, number-formatting

I'm looking for a JavaScript library which can parse and format date values and numbers. It should not be too big or complicated just 4 methods would suffice for me: parseDate, formatDate, parseNumber, formatNumber

```
//dt is a JavaScript date object, str a string containing a date, formatoptions specifies the format
var dt = parseDate(str, formatoptions);
var str = formatDate(dt, formatoptions);
//same applies for parseNumber and formatNumber just replace dt with nr which represents a JavaScript number
```

I've already asked Mr. Google but there are sooo many libraries and articles out there that it is hard to find something good. Many libs can format a number or date but can't parse them. Or they are not stable (reasonably bug-free).

Any recommendations?

**update:**

- Sadly serverside processing is not really on option. I know support for date and time manipulation is much better in PHP or ASP
- I included some sample code what I would expect from the parse and format functions

**update 2:**

I found quite a good library for formatting numbers which is called [jquery-numberformatter](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/)

Comment: Ugh. Dates and javascript. If back-end processing of the dates is an option, it may be well worth considering. Dealing with dates and times in javascript can be very painful, in my experience. I had quite an ordeal figuring out how to safely handle daylight savings changes in javascript for a TV schedule project I worked on.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what the four functions should expect as input and what they should output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using date.js from http://www.datejs.com. The parser in the home page will give you an idea of its capabilities.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this one before. It's huge and definitely covers what I need but I think it is not really stable. Right now there are 86 open issues in the issue-list and the word "Alpha" in the name of the download makes me a little nervous.

Comment: bah! as far as I am concerned, most software around is "Alpha" ;)

Comment: Yes, that's one of my problems finding a library. BUT if you really recommend it - I'll maybe give it a try.

Comment: I am not recommending it in any specific way. I had a project involving dates and some nasty overlapping date ranges a while ago, and I remember ending up using it for a few of the functions, mainly having to do with date differences, and converting dates to total days elapsed from some set start time. I have not really used it for parsing, so I cannot say I have much experience in that direction, but the demo looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

These days I would look at [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/).  Theres plenty of documentation and tests.